# Какой поток передает данные во View

Tags: java, android, mvp, android-threads

Допустим MVP. В презентере определен интерфейс для колбека

```
dataManager.downloadDataFromNetwork(currentDate, ACCESS_KEY, currentCurrency, new Callback<PostModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<PostModel> call, Response<PostModel> response) {
                    PostModel postModel = response.body();
                    validationOfData(postModel);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<PostModel> call, Throwable t) {
                    getView().showToast("Сетевая ошибка");
                }
            });
```

Вью передает данные в презентер, в презентере реализуется интерфейс и далее фреймворк `retrofit 2` осуществляет вызов в сеть. До этого момента всё выполнял главный поток приложения. Тут главный поток "освобождается" и продолжает слушать действия пользователя.
 Дальше осуществляется запрос в сеть в доп. потоке. Результат передается в реализацию интерфейса колбека, который лежит в презентер. Я так понимаю всё это делает доп. поток. И он же вызывает методы интерфейса вью и  обновляет вью.. Правильно ли я всё понимаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том , что ретрофит исполняет колбек в `UI` потоке. Всё реализовано в ретрофит под "капотом".  `UI` нельзя трогать из доп. потоков.  `runOnUiThread` предназначен для передачи исполнения главному потоку.